# Add Mobile Page to ASP.Net Web App

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.Net 4.5 Web application written with asp.net. I want to add mobile pages to the project.

Is it possible to add mobile page to ASP.Net 4.5 Web Application?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a mobile page? You can point a mobile browser at any web page?

Comment: @Liath I think he might be referring to the old "Mobile Web Forms" feature from ASP.NET 1.1 (which were meant for old-style WAP browsers). AFAIK that feature is deprecated.

Comment: i'm referring to have a mobile page in my web app so user who use mobile will be redirected to page for mobiles only. i know this is possible in MVC but i don't know how to develop web app in MVC. and my time is running out... :(